# SQL Server Replace Multi Value _ string in column based on condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column that stores select statements, and I marked every column with a number, and I store this number in another table.

This is sample data :

```
CREATE TABLE #Table 
(Cmd Nvarchar(Max) )

INSERT #Table
    SELECT
        'select FacilityId as [Id] ,Fld00012 as [English Name] ,Fld00011 as [Arabic Name] ,TypeCode as [Facility Type] ,ParentFacilityId,Fld00027 as [Photo] From Facilities Where ( ( (Facilities.TypeCode = ''Application'')   OR   (Facilities.TypeCode = ''Company'')   OR   (Facilities.TypeCode = ''Folder'')   OR   (Facilities.TypeCode = ''Module'')   OR   (Facilities.TypeCode = ''PhysicalView'')   OR   (Facilities.TypeCode = ''Query'')   OR   (Facilities.TypeCode = ''SheetWindow'')   OR   (Facilities.TypeCode = ''SSRS'')   OR   (Facilities.TypeCode = ''FacilityGenerator'')   OR   (Facilities.TypeCode = ''SystemMenu'')   OR   (Facilities.TypeCode = ''SetGenerator'')  ) AND   (Facilities.state != ''Removed'')  ) '

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'select Lookup(ParentFacilityId,Company,Name_En) as [Company Name] ,Lookup(ParentFacilityId,Company,Name_Ar) as [Company Name Ar] ,Fld00068 as [StartDate] ,Fld00333 as [MonthDays] , Facilities.state as [State] ,Lookup(revised_by,User,Name_En) as [User Name En] ,Lookup(revised_by,User,Name_Ar) as [User Name Ar] ,FacilityId as [Id],ParentFacilityId,TypeCode as [Facility Type],Fld00027 as [Photo] From Facilities Where ((  (Facilities.TypeCode = ''HRSetting'')   AND   (Facilities.state != ''Removed'')  )) '

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'select FacilityId as [Id] ,Fld00011 as [Role Name Ar] ,Fld00012 as [Role Name] ,Fld00028 as [Description] , Facilities.state as [State] ,Lookup(revised_by,User,Name_En) as [User Name] ,Lookup(revised_by,User,Name_Ar) as [User Name Ar] ,ParentFacilityId,TypeCode as [Facility Type],Fld00027 as [Photo] From Facilities Where ((  (Facilities.TypeCode = ''Role'')   AND   (Facilities.state != ''Removed'')  )) '

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'select TypeCode as [Facility Type] ,FacilityId as [Id] ,ParentFacilityId as [ParentFacilityId] , Facilities.state as [State] ,Fld00011 as [Name Ar] ,Fld00012 as [Name En] ,Lookup(ParentFacilityId,Installation,Name_En) as [Installation Name En] ,Fld00027 as [Photo] From Facilities Where ((  (Facilities.TypeCode = ''Company'')  )) '

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'select FacilityId as [Id] ,Fld00011 as [Name Ar] ,Fld00012 as [Name] ,Fld00006 as [Birth Date] ,Lookup(Fld00039,CountryNation,Name_En) as [Nationality] ,Lookup(Fld00039,CountryNation,Name_Ar) as [CountryNation Name Ar] , Facilities.state as [State] ,Fld00001 as [User Name] ,ParentFacilityId,TypeCode as [Facility Type],Fld00027 as [Photo] From Facilities Where ((  (Facilities.TypeCode = ''User'')   AND   (Facilities.state != ''Removed'')  )) '

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'select FacilityId as [Id] ,Fld00012 as [Name En] ,Fld00011 as [Name Ar] , Facilities.state as [State] ,ParentFacilityId,TypeCode as [Facility Type],Fld00027 as [Photo] From Facilities Where ((  (Facilities.TypeCode = ''Department'')   AND   (Facilities.state != ''Removed'')  )) '

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'select Fld00011 as [Name Ar] ,Fld00012 as [Bank Name] , Facilities.state as [State] ,Fld00055 as [BankCode] ,Lookup(revised_by,User,Name_En) as [User Name] ,Lookup(revised_by,User,Name_Ar) as [User Name Ar] , Facilities.revised_at as [Revised At] ,FacilityId as [Id],ParentFacilityId,TypeCode as [Facility Type],Fld00027 as [Photo] From Facilities Where ((  (Facilities.TypeCode = ''Bank'')   AND   (Facilities.state != ''Removed'')  ))  Order by Facilities.FacilityId DESC'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'select Fld00011 as [Name Ar] ,Fld00012 as [Name] , Facilities.state as [State] ,Lookup(revised_by,User,Name_En) as [User Name] ,Lookup(revised_by,User,Name_Ar) as [User Name Ar] , Facilities.revised_at as [Revised At] ,FacilityId as [Id],ParentFacilityId,TypeCode as [Facility Type],Fld00027 as [Photo] From Facilities Where (  (Facilities.TypeCode = ''Governorate'')   AND   (Facilities.state != ''Removed'')  ) '

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'select FacilityId as [Id] ,Fld00011 as [Name Ar] ,Fld00012 as [Name] , Facilities.state as [State] ,Lookup(revised_by,User,Name_En) as [User Name] ,Lookup(revised_by,User,Name_Ar) as [User Name Ar] , Facilities.revised_at as [Revised At] ,ParentFacilityId,TypeCode as [Facility Type],Fld00027 as [Photo] From Facilities Where ((  (Facilities.TypeCode = ''sponsor'')   AND   (Facilities.state != ''Removed'')  )) '

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'select Fld00011 as [Name Ar] ,Fld00012 as [Name En] , Facilities.state as [State] ,FacilityId as [Id],ParentFacilityId,TypeCode as [Facility Type],Fld00027 as [Photo] From Facilities Where (  (Facilities.TypeCode = ''License'')   AND   (Facilities.state != ''Removed'')  ) '

SELECT cmd FROM #Table
```

Column Number table:

```
CREATE TABLE #FieldNumber
(Old_Fld_No bigInt, New_Fld_NO BigInt)

INSERT INTO #FieldNumber
VALUES (11, 1320), (12, 1450), 
       (27, 1260), (68, 2065)
```

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNquJ.png)

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kwSN.png)

What I need to replace every `FldNo000` [Old_Fld_No] with new `FldNo000` [New_Fld_No]

For example: Fld00012 ==> Fld0001450

and do it for all rows

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for :

```
  begin
     declare pcursor cursor for select distinct old_fld_no,new_fld_no from 
   fieldnumber ;
    declare @old_fld_no Bigint;
    declare @new_fld_no Bigint;
    open pcursor
       fetch next from pcursor into @old_fld_no,@new_fld_no 
       while (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
           begin
                UPDATE TAB 
                SET CMD =REPLACE(CMD,@OLD_FLD_NO,@NEW_FLD_NO)
                fetch next from pcursor into @old_fld_no,@new_fld_no 
           end 
   close pcursor
  deallocate pcursor
end
```